# How to get started with taking a dynamic model class and filling it with data

Tags: .net, dynamic, reflection

I have a small routing engine. It matches patterns and populates a dictionary of route-parameters. So `/blog/{action}/{id}` will match `/blog/view/123` and put `123` as the value to the key of `id` in a dictionary and so on.

Here comes the fun part. I want to change this system to instead use a model-type architecture, so I can instead have something like

```
class BlogRoute
{
    [RouteParam("action")]
    public string Action{get;set;}
    [RouteParam("id")]
    public string ID{get;set;}
}
```

Of course, there are other route "models" as well such as `/comments/{action}/{entryid}/{id}` and so on, so I need to do this I believe with reflection

My end goal is basically to have something like `AddRoute("pattern", new BlogRoute())` or similar and my router dynamically fill data into the BlogRoute instance

How would I get started doing this? I've not used reflection hardly at all(though oddly very familiar with IL) and it seems a bit daunting and I'm afraid of doing it in a sub-optimal way since this is a bit performance critical. This is also done in multiple other libraries. Basically every ORM does something similar to this. Are there any tutorials or such for getting started with something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Just go through the properties that have the RouteParam attribute on them. If you get the value passed to the constructor of the attribute and the value of the property itself on some route information object passed to AddRoute, you can obtain all route information.

I'm not sure if reflection is noticeably slow, but I'd stay away from it in performance critical situations. You can replace this method of using reflection with one in which you have a RouteData class simply with a dictionary in it. But you loose the beautiful declarative way of doing things. You choose.

```
/// <summary>
/// This is your custom attribute type that you will use to annotate properties as route information.
/// </summary>
class RouteParamAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string RouteKey;
    public RouteParamAttribute(string routeKey)
    {
        RouteKey = routeKey;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// From which all other routes inherit. This is optional and is used to avoid passing any kind of object to AddRoute.
/// </summary>
class Route
{

}

/// <summary>
/// This is an actual route class with properties annotated with RouteParam because they are route information pieces.
/// </summary>
class BlogRoute : Route
{
    [RouteParam("action")]
    public string Action { get; set; }
    [RouteParam("id")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// This is all the reflection happen to add routes to your route system.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="routeInformation"></param>
void AddRoute(Route routeInformation)
{
    //Get the type of the routeInformation object that is passed. This will be used 
    //to get the route properties and then the attributes with which they are annotated.
    Type specificRouteType = routeInformation.GetType(); //not necessarily Route, could be BlogRoute.

    //The kind of attribute that a route property should have.
    Type attribType = typeof(RouteParamAttribute);

    //get the list of props marked with RouteParam (using attribType).
    var routeProperties = specificRouteType.GetProperties().Where(x => x.GetCustomAttributes(attribType, false).Count() >= 1);

    //this where we'll store the route data.
    Dictionary<string, string> routeData = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    //Add the data in each route property found to the dictionary
    foreach (PropertyInfo routeProperty in routeProperties)
    {
        //Get the attribute as an object (because in it we have the "action" or "id" or etc route key).
        var rpa = routeProperty.GetCustomAttributes(attribType, false).First() as RouteParamAttribute;

        //The value of the property, this is the value for the route key. For example if a property
        //has an attribute RouteParam("action") we would expect the value to be "blog" or "comments"
        var value = routeProperty.GetValue(routeInformation, null);

        //convert the value to string (or object depending on your needs, be careful 
        //that it must match the dictionary though)
        string stringValue = "";
        if (value != null)
            stringValue = value.ToString();
        else ; //throw an exception?

        routeData.Add(rpa.RouteKey, stringValue);
    }

    //now you have a dictionary of route keys (action, id, etc) and their values
    //manipulate and add them to the route system
}
```

Comment: This actually is backwards from what I was intending, though it is a great start for going the other way (which I will exactly need for routing to generate URLs from "route models" )